# "Target host not specified" when using json data for Dynamic Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

I have upgraded to version 1.0.0 and I am encountering an error that was working fine when using 0.9.6.

Below is a provided Karate sample code which I modified a bit to show how I get the error.

```
 Background:
    * url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    * def id = read("id-list.json")

 Scenario Outline: [id: <id>] get all users and then get the first user by id
    Given path 'users', <id>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * print id

  Examples:
    | id |
```

**id-list.json**

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

Error:

```
Testing started at 11:12 ...
command: --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --name ^\[id\: .*\] get all users and then get the first user by id$ --glue com.intuit.karate C:/Users/danna/IdeaProjects/YXC/src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature
11:12:19.580 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
11:12:19.585 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - backed up existing 'target\karate-reports' dir to: target\karate-reports_1616551939583
11:12:19.606 [main] INFO  c.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime - found scenario at line: 18 - ^\[id\: .*\] get all users and then get the first user by id$
11:12:20.265 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:12:20.333 [main] INFO  c.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime - found scenario at line: 18 - ^\[id\: .*\] get all users and then get the first user by id$
11:12:20.338 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:12:20.595 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified, http call failed after 250 milliseconds for url: /users/1
11:12:20.596 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12
When method get
http call failed after 250 milliseconds for url: /users/1
src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12

http call failed after 250 milliseconds for url: /users/1
src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12
11:12:20.596 [main] INFO  c.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime - found scenario at line: 18 - ^\[id\: .*\] get all users and then get the first user by id$
11:12:20.600 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null 
11:12:20.601 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified, http call failed after 0 milliseconds for url: /users/2
11:12:20.601 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12
When method get
http call failed after 0 milliseconds for url: /users/2
src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12

http call failed after 0 milliseconds for url: /users/2
src/test/java/examples/users/users.feature:12
```

I think the error was related to this [issue](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1517) but I'm not quite sure .
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This sounds like it is related to the same bug, so we have noted it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1517#issuecomment-805439326

For now you can work around by moving the `url` line into the first line of the `Scenario`.